# How to change a <td> tag's internal value?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to make it so when you click on one of the `<td>`s in the table, the SVG will appear in it.
This is a version of my code with four slots instead of 64, but the functions are the same:

```js
function addPiece() {
  document.getElementsByName("square").innerHTML = document.write("<svg width='100' height='100'> <circle cx='50' cy='50', r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' fill='white' /> </svg>");
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: #459f60;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 2px solid #808080">
  <tr>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="0-0" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="0-1" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="1-0" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="1-1" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem with this code is that it just replaces the whole thing with the SVG instead of inputting it inside the `<td>` that was clicked.
It will be very appreciated to get some help here as I'm really low level in js and html.

Comment: You don't need that `document.write` at all. Just set the `innerHTML` to the string that you want.

Comment: On top of @Aioros comment, you can take a look at how you can create an `<svg>` element programmatically here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701705/programmatically-creating-an-svg-image-element-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using `document.write`. This will override your whole document HTML. Use `.innerHTML` attribute instead to override the HTML inside your selected element.

Notice that in my code snippet I added id for the elements and I passed it to the function call.

```js
function addPiece(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<svg width='100' height='100'> <circle cx='50' cy='50', r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' fill='white' /> </svg>"
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: #459f60;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 2px solid #808080">
  <tr>
    <td class="square" id="square1" name="square" id="0-0" onclick="addPiece(this.id)"></td>
    <td class="square" id="square2" name="square" id="0-1" onclick="addPiece(this.id)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="square" id="square3" name="square" id="1-0" onclick="addPiece(this.id)"></td>
    <td class="square" id="square4" name="square" id="1-1" onclick="addPiece(this.id)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

HTML attributes does not support single qoutes as you're using in javascript.

```
<table style="border: 2px solid #808080" id="table">
  <tr>
      <td class="square" id="square1" name="square">d</td>
      <td class="square" id="square2" name="square">s</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="square" id="square3" name="square">dd</td>
      <td class="square" id="square4" name="square">eee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is it's **Jquery** code to show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table td').click(function(){
    var addhtml='<svg width="100" height="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50", r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="white" /> </svg>';
    $(this).html(addhtml);
  })
});
```

When using jquery **No need to add function in very element**. You can call them simply using this class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `document.write()` is useless here.
You should instead try like this:

```js
document.getElementsByName("square").innerHTML = "<svg width='100' height='100'> <circle cx='50' cy='50', r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' fill='white' /> </svg>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use document.write to set content into html DOM. As its name, document.write set content to whole document (overwrite whole html). Just pass the content with innerHTML directly.

```js
function addPiece() {
  document.getElementsByName("square").innerHTML = "<svg width='100' height='100'> <circle cx='50' cy='50', r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' fill='white' /> </svg>";
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: #459f60;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 2px solid #808080">
  <tr>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="0-0" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="0-1" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="1-0" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
    <td class="square" name="square" id="1-1" onclick="addPiece()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```